# When my app enters foreground, view is not reloaded with refresh data

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a problem regarding reload of view.

I use tabbar in my application.  When I press home button and my app is in background.  Now my problem is start now.  I Want that every time my first tab is display. 
So, every time I get 1st tabbar's view.  But When I get 1st tabbar's view, I call `viewDidAppear()` of 1st tabar's viewController in AppDelegate like below:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

     self.tabBarController.selectedViewController=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
     [navigationController1 popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     [navigationController2 popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     [navigationController3 popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     [navigationController4 popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     [navigationController5 popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

     simpleTableViewController *s = [[simpleTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"simpleTableViewController" bundle:nil];
     [s viewDidAppear:YES];
}
```

So,`viewDidAppear()` is called and data is loaded and log is printed.  But view is not reloaded or refreshed. Means there is not any effect in tableview. Data which is loaded from server is displayed in tableview.

I use the following code for reload or refresh view:

```
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
        [tabledata reloadData];
```

But it is not effected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you're calling:

```
simpleTableViewController *s = [[simpleTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"simpleTableViewController" bundle:nil];
[s viewDidAppear:YES];
```

You are simply creating a **new** instance of that view controller and attempting asking it to refresh it's data. Not the view controller that is already in the navigation stack.

I suggest that you add your `simpleTableViewController` as an observer for the "application did become active" or "will enter foreground" notification. E.g.:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

Then in the notification handler you can reload your data:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self reloadDataFromWeb];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observer in the `simpleTableViewController`'s `dealloc` method.

Comment: Thank u very much for solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `viewDidAppear`.  Show your view controller and iOS will call your `viewDidAppear` for you when the view truly appears.

Comment: I want to load my view when my app get in foreground.  Then how can i do that ?